# Scraping a wish.com using puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

anyone have luck on scraping wish.com?

i tried but seriously its a bit hard than expected.

from login page it always gives me an error timeout.

need help.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
        await page.setViewport({width:960,height:768});
        await page.goto('https://www.wish.com', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})
        
        const emailInput = '[placeholder="Email Address"][autocomplete="email"]'
        const emailWords = 'test_account@gmail.com'
        await page.waitForSelector( emailInput, { timeout: 0 })
        await page.focus(emailInput)
        await page.keyboard.type(emailWords)

        const passwordInput = 'input[placeholder="Password"][autocomplete="current-password"]'
        const passwordWords = 'testpassword'
        await page.waitForSelector( passwordInput, { timeout: 0 })
        await page.focus(passwordInput)
        await page.keyboard.type(passwordWords)

        await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'wish.png' })

        await Promise.all([
            page.keyboard.press('Enter'),
            page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 1000000 }),
        ])

        await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'wish2.png' })

        await page.goto('https://www.wish.com/search/nike', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000})

        //await browser.close();
        (async() => {
            browser.close();
          })();
})();
```

Comment: I tested your code and you have a captcha to solve on login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are in low network speed that could be happen. I solved with by using this code.

await page.waitFor(10000) to set wait 10 seconds to connect network. You can set any seconds with waitFor functions

Hope this helps you a lot.

Regards